# Configure single property file for multiple enviornment

Tags: java, configuration

How can I configure a single config (property/xml) file for multiple environments? Something like:

```
<env="dev">
<webservice-url>http:server1:1010</webservice-url>
</env>
<env="preprod">
<webservice-url>http:server2:1010</webservice-url>
</env>
<env="prod">
<webservice-url>http:server3:1010</webservice-url>
</env>
```

Here env value is given as a JVM arguement(-D option) like -D=preprod.

Comment: Your are right path. Where are you stuck?

Comment: If they are simple properties, it is simpler to use a properties file per environment and only load the appropriate one based on your vm argument.  No xml required.

Comment: @SurajChandran I am confused with how to get this xml file loaded for application.

Comment: Are you running a standalone jvm or running inside a web-container?

Comment: @SurajChandran WebContainer. Tomcat/JBoss to be specific.

Comment: Your question seems to contain what you are expecting. Instead of combining into one, you can have multiple property files like dev.properties, preprod.properties etc and load the one according to the environment.

Comment: @javauser1 I have already implemented multiple property files but now my architect is asking single property file with multiple envs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the name of the environment as a prefix for the property name.

```
dev.webservice-url=http:server1:1010
preprod.webservice-url=http:server2:1010
prod.webservice-url=http:server3:1010
```

If you specify the JVM option as `-Ddeployment=dev`, then you can access the appropriate one as follows:

```
propertyName = System.getProperty("deployment") + ".webservice-url";
url = props.getProperty(propertyName);
```